# Delete all non-word characters between two words

Tags: deletion

I am often in a situation where there are two words with a bunch of symbols in between like this:

```
word1|); }; } word2
```

Now I'd like to delete those symbols + whitespace between the words and maybe replace them with a single space, depending on what I want to do afterwards. This should work similar to `M-\` and `C-SPC` but for non-word characters other than whitespace too:

```
word1| word2
```

`M-d` does delete those symbols but it also deletes the word behind them which I don't want:

```
word1|
```

`C-SPC M-f M-b C-w` technically works but is cumbersome.

Bonus: Sometimes I also only want to delete one set of symbols (separated by whitespace):

```
word1| }; } word2
```

In all of these cases I usually revert to using evil-mode with its definition of a word and delete operation but I'd like to have a pure emacs solution in my toolbelt too.

Comment: A solution to this problem would be to just delete everything up to the beginning of the next word but I have not found a way to do that either.

Answer (score 3):

Select the region where you want this occur, and

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \W+ RET <space>
```

C-M % \W+ RET

### Other solution :

Evaluate and save in your init file :

```
(defun removes-all-no-letter ()
  "Removes any non-alphabetic character around the point or following the current word.
 Insert a space char instead."
  (interactive)
  (while (looking-at-p "\\w") (forward-char))
  (while (looking-at-p "\\W") (backward-char))
  (forward-char) (while (looking-at-p "\\W") (delete-char 1))
  (insert " "))

(bind-key "C-c u" #'removes-all-no-letter)
```

I arbitrarely bind the function to C-c u, The choice is yours.

Comment: That's even more cumbersome than the `C-SPC M-f M-b C-w` I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Your solution only applies to one case, and requires the point to be at a particular location. Mine deals with all the intervals between two words of any region of any size.
You can easily create a macro or a function and associate it with a key combination of your choice.

Comment: Maybe the function I have add will enjoy you better.